# Failed converting xacro to urdf

Tags: xacro, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the command **rosrun xacro xacro.py ur5.urdf.xacro > ur5.urdf**, the result is not as good as I expected.

> xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254999/failed-converting-xacro-to-urdf/) by [Chunting](https://answers.ros.org/users/27048/chunting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-18**:
Could I please ask you to *not* cross-post questions like these to both ROS Answers *and* the package's issue tracker ([universal_robot#288](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/288))? Besides bad etiquette, it leads to duplication of effort and reduced visibility of solutions.

**Comment by [Chunting](https://answers.ros.org/users/27048/chunting/) on 2017-02-18**:
Thanks for your kind remainder. I published this issue here firstly, then I think Universal_robot is the more suitable category, so I pulbished a second time. Sorry for my mistake and I will pay attention to your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe try the ur5_robot.urdf.xacro file instead because I think that ur5.urdf.xacro just defines the macro, and the ur5_robot.urdf.xacro *uses* the macro here: https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/1c07a163c5b649fb94b5c814945a01e3c506b647/ur_description/urdf/ur5_robot.urdf.xacro#L12

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-18**:
This is indeed the cause. `ur5.urdf.xacro` is not a *top-level* xacro, but only defines a macro. The `ur5_robot.urdf.xacro` is the one instantiating the model, and should those be used.

See also [universal_robot#288](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/288).

**Comment by [Chunting](https://answers.ros.org/users/27048/chunting/) on 2017-02-18**:
Thank you for your help, it works now. That is indeed the cause.

**Comment by [vincentgoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/86736/vincentgoh/) on 2021-10-08**:
-Code:
"rosrun xacro xacro --inorder -o E:\work\universal_robot-kinetic-devel\ur_description\urdf\ur5_robot.urdf E:\work\universal_robot-kinetic-devel\ur_description\urdf\ur5_robot.urdf.xacro"

-Error:
"xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
←[91mresource not found: ur_description
ROS path [0]=c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\share\ros
ROS path [1]=c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\share←[0m
when processing file: E:\work\universal_robot-melodic-devel\ur_description\urdf\ur10_robot.urdf.xacro"

Can someone help me?